# no me reconoce mi terminal

Tags: git, github, terminal

cambie de computadora y me encuentro con este nuevo error, e intentado de varias formas y no logro resolverlo. Serán[image: captura de pantalla] tan amables de darme una manito por favor.

Comment: ¿Has ejecutado los comandos que te dicen después de "Run" ?

Comment: Tienes que completar la [configuración inicial](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+configuracion+inicial) de GIT.